# Найти все Keys начинающие на определенную букву

Tags: python

Как проверить на наличие определенного ключа в `AVLTree`, чтобы не через все ключи итерировать, а через поиск со скоростью `log(n)`.

Смысл в том, что у меня есть список городов `Keys` и инфа к ним как `Value`

Нужно, например, найти все города на букву `B`.

Как сделать запрос правильно, что есть ли вообще `Key` который начинается на `В` и выдать его `Value`

[image: скриншот кода]

Comment: Например, вот так можно получить значения всех ключей, начинающихся на 'A': `[cities.get(k) for k in cities.keys() if k.startswith('А')]`

Comment: А можно пример входных данных?

Comment: Пример вводных данных:  Å Norway 1162 63.967222 10.218611
Aa Estonia 190 59.423611 27.1525
Aach Germany 2127 47.845556 8.851667
Aachen Germany 260454 50.783333 6.083333

Comment: @Владимир, код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, а не в виде скриншота. Все дополнения к вопросу также должны быть в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функциями `ceiling_item` и `succ_item`. Из [документации](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.7):

- `ceiling_item(key)` возвращает пару `(k, v)`, где `k` это наименьший ключ, больший чем `key` (здесь `key` необязательно является ключом в дереве).
- `succ_item(key)` возвращает пару `(k,v)`, где `k` это ключ, следующий за ключом `key`.

Обе функции работают за `O(log(n))`

```
from bintrees import AVLTree

tree = AVLTree()
tree.insert('a', 1)
tree.insert('b1', 2)
tree.insert('b2', 3)
tree.insert('c', 4)


def entries_which_keys_starts_with(letter):
    try:
        # получаем наименьший ключ, начинающийся на букву letter
        key, value = tree.ceiling_item(letter)
    except KeyError:
        # в дереве нет элементов с ключами, первая буква которых >= letter
        return []

    entries = []
    try:
        while key[0] == letter:
            entries.append((key, value))
            key, value = tree.succ_item(key)
    except KeyError:
        # сюда код зайдёт, если первая буква наибольшего ключа в дереве равна letter
        pass
    return entries


entries = entries_which_keys_starts_with('b')
print(entries)  # [('b1', 2), ('b2', 3)]
```